# Deactivate an Ubuntu LiveUSB, make it unbootable without reformatting

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, bootloader

In a previous life I used a certain USB drive to install Ubuntu on a server. After installing I deleted all the files and started using it for storing copies of backups.

Some time later I rebooted the machine with the USB drive still plugged in. It attempted to boot to the USB stick and ended up blowing up when it couldn't find a kernel to load.

**How do I *stop* this drive from being bootable?** I have new stuff on it, so I don't really want to reformat it. Is there a lightweight way to remove the bootable portion of the disk without destroying the whole thing?

It was created using the Make Startup Disk application, [per official documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) from a standard Ubuntu ISO.

Comment: Did you use the USB on Ubuntu or Windows ??

Comment: Do you remeber which program you used to burn the drive?

Comment: You need to zero out the MBR. Something like `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1` should do it.

Comment: @mikewhatever Want to commit that to an answer? It *sounds* right but a bit of explanation about the `bs=446` would be appreciated before I run it :)

Answer (score 2):

Wiping the USB stick's [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) should make it unbootable. We only want to wipe the first 446 bytes which contain the boot code, and leave the rest intact, since it contains the partition table.

The following comand will zero out the required area, by writing zeros to the first 446 bytes of the MBR.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1
```

PS: The X in /dev/sdX should be replaced with the letter from the device name.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by diabling the boot flag

1. Open the disk using `fdisk` tool

   ```
   sudo fdisk /dev/sdX
   ```
2. `p` to show the current table
3. `a` then the number of boot-able partition (the one with `*` in the previous table), to unset the boot flag
4. `w` save & quit